# Pull 5V using NodeMCU output pins

Tags: power, esp8266, 5v, nodemcu

This diagram is of the little device to read the data from P1 port on the DSMR electric meter. In my case it is Landis E360.

[image]

RTS and 5V pins are shorted in the diagram and that is to trigger the data being constantly sent out of the port.

Now I would like instead to trigger data being sent occasionally by pulling RTS high to 5V. I want to do it programmatically using one of the NodeMCUs/ESP8266 out pins.

- How do I modify the the schematic to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: use a logic level n-channel fet. source to rts, drain to 5v, gate to the pin. might also need a 20k between rts(or source) and gnd.

Comment: What about this new diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple** lazy solution:

You need to pull the RTS up to 5V with some 10k and simply put another NPN from RTS line to ground, which the base (with resistor as usual) goes to the GPIO. GPIO goes high - you have current base, NPN conducts and pulls RTS low. If you want to revert this behavior (say, you send data less frequently, and you don't want to permanently waste base current and pull-up current to keep RTS low), then you use classic 2-transistor circuit, seen many times in laptops.

**Smarter** "proper" solution to waste less power (revert GPIO input, I assume more often then not you are NOT sending the data over time, which kinda makes sense?):

Look at the pic. Ch1 can be 3.3V or 5V signal, and it will drive 24V load.
R23 is optional, but can't hurt. Notice, that R23 and R24 make a voltage divider, so they have to be at least 1 order a magnitude difference, better two, then its effects can be completely ignored. MOSFETs can be replaced with BJTs (with all necessary changes in resistors surrounding them, such as adding base resistors and removing pull-ups and pull-downs, but principle is the same: N-channel pulls gate of P-channel low, or NPN pulls the base of PNP low).

**Briefly about idea**: Ch1 goes up, Q19 starts to conduct, the gate of Q20, which was at 24V through the pullup R25, is not pulled low to the ground. Since it's a gate of a P-channel, P-channel opens and supplies 24V out. If Ch1 signal is low, the gate of Q19 is low, Q19 doesn't conduct, so the base of Q20 stays pulled up to 24V. You can apply these principles with your circuits. Again, you can build a similar thing out of BJTs.

In your case you drive RTS - you either supply it with 5V, or you close the valve and it's 0V.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Power consumption is not so important right now so the easy solution is fine. I have made a new drawing using your input. Can you just double check that I have not missed anything?

Comment: I attached a new diagram above  and use the logic that when GPIO goes high RTS connects to 5V and the data flow. Did I miss anything?

Comment: RTS part looks correct

Comment: Since i will be runnung im inverted mode do I still need R3? By inverted I mean what was your suggestion Ilya to use high signal from gpio to trigger connection of Rts to 5v. Will it not jeopardize the whole logic?

Comment: If you use double mosfet configuration, you can see, the P-channel's output doesn't have any pull-up or pull-down, but you want to keep RTS fixed at 0 when you don't want it high. It may actually need a pull-down after the mosfet so that when the mosfet doesn't supply 5V to it, the line would discharge itself to 0 and stay there instead of floating

Comment: As you noticed I am not an expert and just a learning this so please bear with me:) If I understand it correctly one more pull down resistor  (10K?) should be connected between RTS and GND right ?

Comment: no, at any instance, you can have either a pullup or a pulldown, not both. If the transistor is supposed to pull the line down, you need a pullup. If the transistor pulls the line up, you need a pulldown resistor. So that when the transistor is not forcing voltage on the RTS line, it wouldn't be floating. You can't have both at the same time, as you will have a voltage divider made of a pullup and pulldown and you will simply ruin all voltage levels. In my schematic, for example, there is R25 pullup,so that when Q19 is not conducting, the gate of Q20 will go to 5V and not float.That's the idea